# Is it possible to create per-instance mixins in C++11?

Tags: c++, scala, c++11, mixins

Is it possible to create mixins in C++ (C++11) - I want to create behavior per instance, not per class.

In Scala I'd do this with anonymous classes

```
val dylan = new Person with Singer
```

Comment: Is template class met your demand?

Comment: Hm. Isn't a mixin more like "create a new type by enhancing another type". That is, its behaviour isn't per-instance.

Comment: @lulyon yes, depeding on amount of code. I'd want a simple usage

Comment: Isn't that a use case for the decorator pattern?

Comment: Doesnt decorator augment and mixin add? I want to sum features.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If these were your existing classes:

```
class Person
{
public:
    Person(const string& name): name_(name) {}
    void name() { cout << "name: " << name_ << endl; }

protected:
    string name_;
};

class Singer
{
public:
    Singer(const string& song, int year): song_(song), year_(year) {}
    void song() { cout << "song: " << song_ << ", " << year_ << endl; }

protected:
    string song_;
    int year_;
};
```

Then you could play around with this concept in C++11

```
template<typename... Mixins>
class Mixer: public Mixins...
{
public:
    Mixer(const Mixins&... mixins): Mixins(mixins)... {}
};
```

to use it like this:

```
int main() {    
    Mixer<Person,Singer> dylan{{"Dylan"} , {"Like a Rolling Stone", 1965}};

    dylan.name();
    dylan.song(); 
}
```

Comment: or `auto dylan = Mixer<Person, Singer> {{"Dylan"} , {"Like a Rolling Stone", 1965}};` to  have the same left-to-right declaration as in Scala.

Comment: From what I underastand of Scala's mixins, they are [stackable](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html), in the sense that the rightmost one in the declaration overrides methods from the entity at its left.

If this is the case, then multiple inheritance will not act the same way, however single, templated inheritance would. In the example given, `Person`  would be a template class that would derive from its own template parameter, something like `auto dylan = Singer<Person>;`.

Comment: With [concepts](https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/02/a-bit-of-background-for-concepts-and-cpp17-bjarne-stroustrup) it should also be possible to implement the equivalent of Scala's [`trait Doubling extends IntQueue`](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html), where `IntQueue` would be a concept.

Answer (score 5):

Besides the static approach suggested by emesx, I'm familiar with at least one C++ library that allows you to build objects out of mixins at run-time. You sacrifice some things like the natural C++ syntax when defining and calling methods, but you gain other benefits like greatly reduced physical dependencies in the code and more flexibility at run-time. Its origins are rooted in the [entity-component systems](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html), which are quite popular in the game development industry and the implementation is quite performant.

https://github.com/iboB/dynamix